# Java VarArgs Declaration In the method declaration issue

Tags: java, android, oop

why cant we have two varargs as parameters in method declaration. why its required to varags as last parameter only.

[image]

Comment: use args[0]; if args not working args is a string array in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two varargs as parameters. If you could, how Java would know what `String` that you are passing corresponds to what parameter?

For example:

```
setData("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

Which `String`s would be assigned to which parameter?

Comment: i m looking for little bit internal implementation. how exactly it happens.

Comment: What internal implementation do you expect from this? Only one vararg is allowed, otherwise, you will run into the problem described in the answer.

Comment: thanks, i got the the ans. I was wrong thinking from method declaration point of view. Never thought how callee can face issues.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler could not know or decide to which parameter an argument should be bound to, especially with multiple varargs of the same type.